# How do I send the data of an (by javascript) dynamically created HTML table to a PHP file to process?

Tags: javascript, php

(first off, I'm very new to JavaScript - HTML/PHP I know a little better)

I would like to send the table data (which is dynamically created by javascript - depending on how many students there are in the database) to a PHP file to process. The table is created and added to HTML-id "create_groups" (which is included in a HTML Form) after the button "Create Groups" has been pressed.

I've tried giving each table row it's own name (`tr.setAttribute('name', students[i][col[0]]);`) which works (at least the browser shows it in the "console" window) but when I press "submit" the Javascript table data isn't transmitted to the create_groups.php. At least I can't seem to get hold of it.

teacher.php

```js
        function createTableFromJSON() {
            hideAll();
            document.getElementById('create_groups').style.display = "block";
    
            let con = new XMLHttpRequest(); //Create Object
    
            console.log("1");
    
            con.open("GET", "teacher_check.php", true); //open the connection
    
            con.onreadystatechange = function() { //define Callback function
    
                if (con.readyState == 4 && con.status == 200) {
    
                    console.log("2");
                    console.log(this.responseText);
                    let response = this.responseText;
                    let students = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
    //Convert String back into JSON object
                    console.log(students);
                    let col = [];
                    for (let key in students[0]) {
                        col.push(key);
                    }
    
                    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
                    let table = document.createElement("table");
    
                    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.
                    let tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW AT THE END
                    let th = document.createElement("th");
                    th.innerHTML = "SELECT";
                    tr.appendChild(th);
                    for (let i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                        let th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
                        th.innerHTML = col[i];
                        tr.appendChild(th);
    
                    }
    
                    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
                    for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
                        tr = table.insertRow(-1);
                        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
                        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
                       
                        
                        console.log(students[i][col[0]]); 
    //this shows the right names
                        
                        tr.appendChild(checkbox);
                        tr.setAttribute('name', students[i][col[0]]);
    
                        
                        for (let j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                            let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                            tabCell.innerHTML = students[i][col[j]];
                            
                        }
                    }
                    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
                    let divContainer = document.getElementById("create_groups");
                    //divContainer.innerHTML = "";
                    divContainer.appendChild(table);
                    document.getElementById("create_groups").submit();
                }
    
            }
    
            con.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //Set appropriate request Header
            con.send(); //Request File Content
        }
    

  function hideAll() {
        document.getElementById('create_groups').style.display = "none";
        
    }
```

```html
    <input type="button" name="create_groups" value="Create Groups" onclick="createTableFromJSON()">
      
    <form action="create_groups.php" method ="post">
    <div class="container white darken-4" id="create_groups" style="display:none;">
           
            <p>
                    <label>
                        <span>Groupname:</span>
                        <input type="text" name="groupname">
                    </label>
                </p>
                
     <p><button type="submit" name ="submit">Submit</button></p>            
    </div>
```

create_groups.php

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $student = $_POST['stud'];
    $groupname = $_POST['groupname'];

   echo $groupname;
   echo $student;
}
```

I expect to be able to access all the names of the students in the create_groups.php file, which are checked off in the other teacher.php file in the table. Obviously the "isChecked" part isn't implemented yet, because the other part doesn't work yet.
So the creating of the table with the correct data works, just not the transmitting to the PHP file.

Comment: Sorry i can't seem to find any mix ups of GET and POST, where do you mean? 
The line "con.open("GET", "teacher_check.php", true);" is getting the data from another document, that works. But apart from that I'm only using the POST method. 

I don't really know what to do with the second half of your answer, could you clarify? Thanks

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't know what is revelant to see for someone to be able to help me. I have cut out quite a lot already..

Comment: The AJAX call to teacher_check.php is only to get the data to be able to create the table. 
What do you mean by doing two AJAXes? Do I need an AJAX to send the form data to another PHP document?

Comment: Why do you have a form submit when the call to `teacher_check.php` is finished btw? Try starting with `var_dump($_POST);` in `create_groups.php`

Comment: @DarkBee I would like to submit the form to another file (create_groups). The AJAx call is only do get the data from the file "teacher_check". But i might well have an error in my logic, as I said, I'm very new at this. 

This is the ouput of the var_dump($_POST) btw:

array(2) { ["groupname"]=> string(10) "alphagroup" ["submit"]=> string(6) "submit" } 

Notice: Undefined index: stud in C:\xampp\htdocs\semesterwork\create_groups.php on line 5

alphagroup

Comment: Well having a look at your javascript. You are creating `checkbox`es BUT your are setting the name onto the `tr` (`tr.setAttribute('name', students[i][col[0]]);`), which is incorrect. I'd also suggest you give the same name (`stud[]`) to each of the checkboxes but fill in the name of the student as value - This will later on create an array with all checked students, you can verfiy this with `var_dump($_POST['stud']);` (and not with `echo`).

Comment: Ah ok interesting.
Setting the name onto the tr is incorrect, because bad programming or because it doesn't work? Because the tr names, when looking at it in the browser "inspect element" the names of the tr's are correct.
 So this way the checked students are saved in the stud[ ] array and i can access and process them later on with the array, correct? 
Thanks, will try this later!

Comment: A `tr` is not an element defined in the [form elements](https://devdojo.com/html/form-elements) so it won't get posted to the backend when a form is submitted

Comment: Good to know! Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: @DarkBee Sorry to ask again, i can't seem to implement it. I've managed to give each individual checkbox the students name of the specific row but not further sadly. Any clues on how to do it maybe?

Answer (score 0):

There is few issues in html syntax and javascript as well please try correcting them.

hideAll() function definition is missing in you script first line. 
Second in html before

tag there is unnecessary ">" character.

Comment: I have taken care of it!

Comment: no sadly not, the mistakes were only there because i tried to format the code in stackoverflow, they weren't in the original code

Comment: May I know the purpose of statement                 document.getElementById("create_groups").submit();
on line 80.
Is this for submitting the form to create_groups.php ?

Comment: Ah no, in the HTML section I have an ID "create_groups". So the table gets created in the container with that ID name.